# Convert stacked line chart to multiple line chart(not stacked) using dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am using dc.js to create multiple line chart. I have created a chart which is a stack chart, I want to change it to multiple line chart.

For example, currently the line stack above each other here, I want them not to stack above each other instead should flow like series chart(it can override each other according to data).

I have render stack in chart using below code

```
for(let key in curr) {
   if(index === 0) {
      subscriptionChart.group(curr[key], key)
   } else {
      subscriptionChart.stack(curr[key], key)
   }
}
```

I am adding a JS fiddle below, Please help me with this. Thank you.

[Stack chart JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpj0ca3f/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the heart of your question is: does it really take a completely different data format in order to draw a series chart instead of a stacked chart?

The answer is unfortunately "yes".

Please try to flatten `transformedSubscriptionData` so that it has one "multikey" and one value per row, e.g. the third row of the current transformed data would be expanded to:

```
[
   {date: Thu Mar 07 2019 10:06:25 GMT-0500, result: 'canceled', count: 22},
   {date: Thu Mar 07 2019 10:06:25 GMT-0500, result: 'active', count: 2},
   {date: Thu Mar 07 2019 10:06:25 GMT-0500, result: 'skip', count: 10},
   ...
]
```

Then it should be pretty obvious from the [series chart example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/series.html) how to generate that chart.

The important setting is

```
chart.seriesAccessor(d => d.result)
```

using the new result column detailed above.

If you run into trouble, please add a section to your question and we can iterate on it.

Comment: Could you tell me how to position y-axis start tick 0 start position little up?

Comment: When you get an answer on Stack Overflow that solves your problem, please click the green checkmark to accept the answer.

Comment: Do you mean, change the Y domain so that there is a little more space, and show a little bit of negative Y? The easiest way to do that is to change the calculation of minimum Y, e.g. `subscriptionChart.yAxisMin = function() { return -4; };` However, the area will only fill from zero up, since that's the true zero.